# Import Excel sheet Data to Sqlite Table in Windows store app

Tags: c#, windows, excel, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I am new to windows store apps, can Anyone  provide me Solution / reference links for Import excel sheet data to sqlite table in windows store apps using C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can read excel file (.xlsx) file  like [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4fce4765-2d05-4a2b-8d0a-6219e87f3307/reading-excel-file-using-c-in-winrt-platform) and insert into Sqlitedb